# Find all row with different value in a column between 2 tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables I want to find when `id` and  `uid` are same, there is a different `fs` vs `FSFG`.  There is also an additional condition that `Num` has to be 6.  Would this be the right query?

```
table t1                table t2
id  fs  Num             uid FSFG
```

My query

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON id = uid
WHERE fs != FSFG AND Num = 6
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Does inner join sound like the right join to use in this case?

Comment: . . If `id` and `uid` need to be the same, then `inner join` is the right `join`.

Comment: "_Would this be the right query?_" Try it and validate your result. If it does not match your expected result, then include some sample data and the expected result in your question. If you want a code review, there is a dedicated site for that: [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

yes, this query is

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON id = uid
WHERE fs != FSFG AND Num = 6
```